# Second process seems to make first process crash (.net, c#)

Tags: asp.net

In a .net-webapplication, I have a module with the following code:

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //..

   itemRepository.Create(store, validFrom);

   Item item = itemRepository.GetByStoreAndValidFrom(store, validFrom);

   //..

}
```

An item is created by the repository and then fetched from the database.
Sometimes, f.ex. if the user clicks on the button twice very quickly, the following seems to happen:
**Two program processes of this module** (please correct if the term not right!) start very closely after each other. Two items are created and the first process crashes because there is more than one item available in the database.
Is there a good way to handle this problem? I thought about putting a javascript blocker into the interface (to prevent the second button click) but would be thankful for hints.

Comment: There is no code related to a process start, etc, could you share something related to a process start?

Comment: Is this a web or desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling the control initiating a postback will cause the form not to be submitted.

The way [I solved](http://devio.wordpress.com/2010/01/27/disabling-submitting-control-in-asp-net/) this problem on the UI is to add another div that will be displayed on top of the web form to prevent repeated submissions. Original article with solution is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153326/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/100406-1.shtml).

Comment: Just for interest, do you handle the case that multiple users execute actions at (nearly) the same time which are only allowed once?

Comment: For multi-user or multi-process scenarios, you should use a Mutex and performs your checks and actions inside the critical section protected by the Mutex